# How to dynamically update a plot in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following snippet that I would like to extend in a way that the data from each loop gets plotted on the same canvas instead of for each loop to a different one.

```
for level in range(len(result)):
  sizes = result[level].values()
  distribution=pd.DataFrame(Counter(sizes).items(), columns=['community size','number of communities'])
  distribution.plot(kind='scatter', x='community size', y='number of communities')
```

In the optimal case I also additionally would like to have the dots in the scatterplot color-coded according to the original data (Dots belonging to the data from one loop colored in the same color).

I am more or less new to both matplotlib and pandas, so andy help is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you upload you sample data please? By the way, is `result` is `dataframe`? If so, the for loop tends to loop it row-by-row, but `result[level]` actually try to access to column `level`. Don't you see any error raised because of this?

Comment: Hi @JianxunLi No, results is not a DataFrame, it is a dictionary. I uploaded the content of it as an example here: http://pastebin.com/j8T1i7Bj so that you can reproduce. Thx already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `plot` many times, you could build the entire data set as one
DataFrame and then you would only need to call `plot` once.

Starting with

```
result = [{0: 21, 1: 7, 2: 67, 3: 12, 4: 15, 5: 7, 6: 54, 7: 49, 8: 50, 9: 31,
           10: 6, 11: 2, 12: 8, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 1, 16: 35, 17: 2, 18: 1, 19:
           4, 20: 2, 21: 4, 22: 3, 23: 1, 24: 1, 25: 1, 26: 1, 27: 1, 28: 1, 
           29: 1}, 
          {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 2, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1,
           11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 1, 16: 1, 17: 1}]
```

you could build a DataFrame with columns `level` and `size`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(level,val) for level, dct in enumerate(result) 
                   for val in dct.values()],
                  columns=['level', 'size'])
```

which looks like this:

```
    level  size
0       0    21
1       0     7
2       0    67
...
45      1     1
46      1     1
47      1     1
```

Now we can group by the level, and count how many items of each `size` there are in each group:

```
size_count = df.groupby(['level'])['size'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())
# level    
# 0      1      9
#        2      5
#        7      2
# ...
# 1      1     11
#        2      4
#        3      2
#        5      1
# dtype: int64
```

The [`groupby/apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) above returns a `pd.Series`. To make this a DataFrame, we can make the index level values into columns by calling `reset_index()`, and then assign column names to the columns:

```
size_count = size_count.reset_index()
size_count.columns = ['level', 'community size', 'number of communities']
```

Now the desired plot can be generated with

```
size_count.plot(kind='scatter', x='community size', y='number of communities', 
                s=100, c='level')
```

`s=100` controls the size of the dots, `c='level'` tells `plot` to color the dots according the value in the `level` column.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

result = [{0: 21, 1: 7, 2: 67, 3: 12, 4: 15, 5: 7, 6: 54, 7: 49, 8: 50, 9: 31,
           10: 6, 11: 2, 12: 8, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 1, 16: 35, 17: 2, 18: 1, 19:
           4, 20: 2, 21: 4, 22: 3, 23: 1, 24: 1, 25: 1, 26: 1, 27: 1, 28: 1, 
           29: 1}, 
          {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 2, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1,
           11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 1, 16: 1, 17: 1}]

df = pd.DataFrame([(level,val) for level, dct in enumerate(result) 
                   for val in dct.values()],
                  columns=['level', 'size'])
size_count = df.groupby(['level'])['size'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())
size_count = size_count.reset_index()
size_count.columns = ['level', 'community size', 'number of communities']
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
size_count.plot(kind='scatter', x='community size', y='number of communities', 
                s=100, c='level', cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Using a colorbar might be appropriate if there are dozens of levels.

---

On the other hand, if there are only a few levels, using a legend would make
more sense. In that case, it is more convenient to call `plot` once for each
level value, since the matplotlib code which makes the legend is set up to make
one legend entry per plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

result = [{0: 21, 1: 7, 2: 67, 3: 12, 4: 15, 5: 7, 6: 54, 7: 49, 8: 50, 9: 31,
           10: 6, 11: 2, 12: 8, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 1, 16: 35, 17: 2, 18: 1, 19:
           4, 20: 2, 21: 4, 22: 3, 23: 1, 24: 1, 25: 1, 26: 1, 27: 1, 28: 1, 
           29: 1}, 
          {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 2, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1,
           11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 1, 16: 1, 17: 1}]

df = pd.DataFrame([(level,val) for level, dct in enumerate(result) 
                   for val in dct.values()],
                  columns=['level', 'size'])
groups = df.groupby(['level'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for level, grp in groups:
    size_count = grp['size'].value_counts()
    ax.plot(size_count.index, size_count, markersize=12, marker='o', 
            linestyle='', label='level {}'.format(level))
ax.legend(loc='best', numpoints=1)
ax.set_xlabel('community size')
ax.set_ylabel('number of communities')
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: very nice @HappyLeapSecond, thx. Is it possible to have a legend on the right border instead of the color bar?

Comment: @vare: I added some code showing how to make a legend instead of a colorbar.